# How can I deserialize using JSON.NET and preserve the parent object

Tags: c#, json.net

I have some JSON like:

```
{
  "companyName": "Software Inc.",
  "employees": [
    {
      "employeeName": "Sally"
    },
    {
      "employeeName": "Jimmy"
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to deserialize it into:

```
public class Company
{
  public string companyName { get; set; }
  public IList<Employee> employees { get; set; }
}

public class Employee
{
  public string employeeName { get; set; }
  public Company employer { get; set; }
}
```

How can I have JSON.NET set the "employer" reference? I tried using a `CustomCreationConverter`, but the `public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)` method doesn't contain a any reference to the current parent object.

Answer (score 2):

That's only going to cause you headaches if you're trying to do that as part of the deserialization. It'd be much easier to perform that task **after** deserialization. Do something like:

```
var company = //deserialized value

foreach (var employee in company.employees)
{
    employee.employer = company;
}
```

Or a one-liner, if you prefer the syntax:

```
company.employees.ForEach(e => e.employer = company);
```

Comment: I know I can manually set up the references, but I have a deep and complex graph that would be much easier to assign references when the object is being created. Do you say it will cause headaches because it is difficult to accomplish using JSON.NET, or because you think it is a bad idea?

Comment: @mprudhom I just think it's a fairly easy task to do post-serialization, but would be difficult to accomplish using JSON.NET. Save yourself the headaches :)

Comment: It actually is pretty trivial to set this up in deserialization. Maybe that was not the case in 2013.

Answer (score 2):

I have handled a similar situation by defining a "[callback](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationCallbacks.htm)" in the parent class like so:

```
    [OnDeserialized]
    private void OnDeserialized(StreamingContext context)
    {
        // Add logic here to pass the `this` object to any child objects
    }
```

This works with JSON.Net without any other setup. I have not actually needed the `StreamingContext` object.

In my case the child objects have a `SetParent()` method that gets called here and also when a new child object is created in other ways.

`[OnDeserialized]` is from `System.Runtime.Serialization`, and so you won't need to add a JSON library reference.

Comment: Thank you! Very straight-forward and intuitive solution (Although it can get messy on large and complicated hierarchies of objects :) Appreciate it.

Answer (score -1):

Json.net solved this with PreserveReferencesHandling. Simply set PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects and Newtonsoft does it all for you.

https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_PreserveReferencesHandling.htm

Regards, 
Fabianus